# Getting an OAuth access token to work for packaged app in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I've created a packaged app for chrome web store which is now published to testers. I need to implement one time payment via Chrome Web Store Payments. for this, according to the documentation, I need to get OAuth access token.

The problem is that I do not see OAuth setup link on my chrome developers dashboard. Thus I can't get it.

In change pricing I've already indicated that my app will use Chrome Web Store Payments.

How to get an OAuth access token?
I understand that this question was bosted before. But it wasnt answered and I really can't figure out how to do it:/ .

Comment: If that question was posted before, then you should delete this question and try to improve the old question. Maybe ask someone to put a bounty on it. Care to give a link to the old question?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be helpful to you: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/check_for_payment

Specifically:

> 1) Upload a ZIP file for your app to the Chrome Developer Dashboard.
>
> **2) In the edit page for your
>   app, click the Change pricing button, choose This application uses
>   Chrome Web Store Payments, and save.**
>
> 3) Get your app's ID, which you can
>   do either as described in Step 5 of Publishing Your App or when you
>   get an OAuth access token.
>
> 4) Get an OAuth access token and token secret
>   so that your app can use the Licensing API.

Comment: Took the liberty of highlighting a key step

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this instead:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Chrome has a browser API to call to get the token.  There is no need to get it from the Developer Dashboard, hence I couldn't find it.  I think much of the documentation is out of date and written before Chrome had the browser API for this.

This URL is likely a good example:

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments